Well my PI screwed me over. Need advice and help with career decision. (MS Life Sciences looking for PhD)
I had written about this earlier too. Current qualifications: MS Life Sciences.
I completed my dissertation this year in May. I completed all my dissertation work required by my program (Int. BS MS) and after my defence, submitted and got the NOC to leave the institute. My dissertation work also has a paper on which I was working on simultaneously. During my thesis submission I got little time to work on it but it was subimtted to a journal already and some minor suggestions were recommended by the reviewers before the final submissiona and publication.
But my supervisor wanted me to continue PhD under him at the institute and promised many incentives during my PhD including completion within 3 years, some papers in high impact factor journals etc. I was reluctant as I had already spent 5 years at the institute (which is no way bad, just new).
I did apply for the PhD interview at the same institute but I also got selected for interviews in IITs (which I wanted to go to). Naturally, he was not happy with MY decision and snapped. I had not completed the paper reviews before the PhD interviews so I informed that I would complete all those after the interviews were over in other institutes. So he abused me verbally that I have been helped too much by him and I not recipocating the same and even threatnened to remove my name from the paper (which he did I think) and even did not provide any recommendation letters.
I am now confused what to do. I have some alternate arrangements for recommendation letters and I will definitely apply for PhD in the January cycle of 2025. Should I continue in academia or should I shift careers?
This may seem like a one sided rant but I am open to all questions. Help me kind people.

Sounds like you and your advisor have an unhealthy relationship. Good luck moving past this and in  creating your career!

We had a healthy relationship and he was commending me at all times until I told him I was appearing for other PhD interviews. There won't be any problem in the future?

You thought you had a healthy relationship. You learned differently when your supervisor reacted negatively to you making your own decisions.

Yep. Was that my fault somehow? I am curious..

No, it was not your fault. Maybe slightly by choosing this person as a MS advisor but it's unlikely you had the information available to make a different decision at that time.

What's an NOC, IIT? Is this possibly in India?

@DanielR.Collins Yep this is in India. A No Objection Certificate required by educational institutions. It signifies that the issuing institution has no objection to the student leaving, typically indicating that the student has fulfilled all obligations and settled any dues. And IITs in India are the best institutions for studying technology and engineering.

@BryanKrause Possibly.

"[NOC] It signifies that the issuing institution has no objection to the student leaving"... Egads, I really feel bad for you folks that have to live with these restrictions.

@DanielR.Collins Same -_-

Let me begin by saying I'm very sorry for your situation. It can be very disorienting and painful to have been treated like this by someone you looked up to. Unfortunately, the power gradient in academia between a PhD advisor and grad student is very high, and gets abused constantly by advisors all over the world. This is not to trivialize your experience, but an attempt to show that sadly this happens a lot and a lot of people overcome this, so you can too.
Now more specific to your situation, the letters of recommendation (LOR) always carry more weight from your immediate manager (in this case advisor). But if your alternate sources also have that capacity, that should still be of comparable weight. And institutes rarely ask why you could not furnish a LOR from your advisor, so that should not be of much concern. Furthermore PhD applications are graded on a variety of factors with LOR being just one of those. If you have a well-rounded application with demonstrable research experience (which seems to be the case), the odds of you getting selected to a good program are higher.
Even if someone asks why you were unable to provide LOR from your advisor, I would refrain from going in to the specifics since it might come across as unprofessional.
Finally, I do not believe that this alone should determine if you should continue in academia or not. Yes, this situation has made things more challenging but not impossible. So if being in academia and getting a PhD is what you want, you should absolutely pursue it to your best abilities. Good luck!

That's really helpful. Thanks!
